# Moving annual total in dax

Tags: dax

How do I calculate mat in dax for same period last year. 
Suppose current mat will be calculated for 2018 Aug - 2019 sep
Same period last year will be calculated for 2017 Aug - 2018 sep

Comment: Do you have a working MAT for current year that you're looking to modify? If yes, take a look at [`PARALLELPERIOD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/parallelperiod-function-dax) or [`SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sameperiodlastyear-function-dax) or [`DATEADD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/dateadd-function-dax) or [`PREVIOUSYEAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/previousyear-function-dax)

Comment: Mat = calculate ( order (sum), datesinperiod (date[date],lastdate(date[date]),-1,yea r).now to calculate if I use 1 instead of -1, does that work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a working [MAT] like in your comment, you should be able to just wrap it in a `CALCULATE` with `SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR`. See below:

```
MAT =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'SillyFact'[Amount] ), 
    DATESINPERIOD ( 'DimDate'[Date], LASTDATE ( 'DimDate'[Date] ), -1, YEAR )
)

MAT Prior = CALCULATE( [MAT], SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ('DimDate'[Date] ) )
```

See them working below in a dummy model:

[image: MAT and MAT Prior]